# codeigniter validation form

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

upload library

```
function upload($upload_path = '', $file_name = ''){
    $config = $this->config($upload_path);
    $this->CI->load->library('upload' ,$config);

    //thuc hien upload
    if($this->CI->upload->do_upload($file_name)){
        $data = $this->CI->upload->data();
    }
    else{
        //khong upload thanh cong
        $data = $this->CI->upload->display_error();
    }
    return $data;
}
function config($upload_path = ''){
    //Khai bao bien cau hinh
    $config = array();
    //thuc mục chứa file
    $config['upload_path']   = $upload_path;
    //Định dạng file được phép tải
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
    //Dung lượng tối đa
    $config['max_size']      = '500';
    //Chiều rộng tối đa
    $config['max_width']     = '1500';
    //Chiều cao tối đa
    $config['max_height']    = '1500';
    //load thư viện upload
    $this->CI->load->library('upload', $config);
    return $config;
}
```

edit action

```
function edit(){
     $id = $this->uri->rsegment('3');
     $news = $this->news_model->get_info($id);

     if(!$news){
         $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Không tồn tại bài viết này');
         redirect(admin_url('news'));
     }
     $this->data['news'] = $news;

     $this->load->library('form_validation'); //load thư viện
     $this->load->helper('form');  //load helper
     /*===============================================validate và update data===========================================*/
     if( $this->input->post() ){
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('title' ,'Tiêu đề bài viết ','required');
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('content' ,'Nội dung bài viết','required');

         if( $this->form_validation-> run()){
             $this->load->library('upload_library');
             $upload_path = './upload/news';
             $upload_data = $this->upload_library->upload($upload_path, 'image');
             $image_link  = $this->news_model->get_info($id, 'image_link') ;

             if( isset($upload_data['file_name']) ){
                     $image_link = $upload_data['file_name'];
             }

             $data = array(
                 'title'      => $this->input->post('title'),
                 'content'    => $this->input->post('content'),
                 'image_link' => $image_link,
                 'meta_desc'  => $this->input->post('meta_desc'),
                 'meta_key'   => $this->input->post('meta_key'),
                 'created'    => now()
             );

             if($this->news_model->update($news->id , $data)){
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Cập nhật dữ liệu thành công');
             }
             else{
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Không cập nhật dữ liệu thành công');
             }
             //chuyển tới trang danh sách quản trị viên
             redirect(admin_url('news'));
         }

     }
     $this->data['temp'] = 'admin/news/edit';
     $this->load->view('admin/main' , $this->data);
}
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UfmI.jpg]

I edited the data are not required to upload photos
when I clicked update button without upload file error occurred

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE5lx.jpg]

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI_Exceptions::show_exception() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\webproduct\system\core\Common.php on line 658 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\webproduct\system\core\Exceptions.php:190 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\webproduct\system\core\Common.php(658): CI_Exceptions->show_exception(Object(Error)) #1 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\webproduct\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 190

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CI_Exceptions::show_exception() must be an instance of Exception, instance of Error given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\webproduct\system\core\Common.php on line 658 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\webproduct\system\core\Exceptions.php:190 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\webproduct\system\core\Common.php(658): CI_Exceptions->show_exception(Object(Error)) #1 [internal function]: _exception_handler(Object(Error)) #2 {main} thrown

Filename: core/Exceptions.php

Line Number: 190

Backtrace:

Comment: Please use the "edit" link to add this information to your OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $this->CI->upload->display_error();
```

this is wrong method call. It should be like this

```
$data = $this->CI->upload->display_errors();
```